# What could [ ... ] near the end of some diagrams in Snowflake's documentation stand for?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Documentation page https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-table.html

What could [ ... ] near the end of the following diagrams stand for?

```
CREATE [ OR REPLACE ] TABLE <table_name> [ ( <col_name> [ <col_type> ] , <col_name> [ <col_type> ] , ... ) ]
  [ CLUSTER BY ( <expr> [ , <expr> , ... ] ) ]
  [ COPY GRANTS ]
  AS SELECT <query>
  [ ... ]

CREATE [ OR REPLACE ] TABLE <table_name>
  [ COPY GRANTS ]
  USING TEMPLATE <query>
  [ ... ]

CREATE [ OR REPLACE ] TABLE <table_name> LIKE <source_table>
  [ CLUSTER BY ( <expr> [ , <expr> , ... ] ) ]
  [ COPY GRANTS ]
  [ ... ]

CREATE [ OR REPLACE ] TABLE <name> CLONE <source_table>
  [ { AT | BEFORE } { TIMESTAMP => <timestamp> | OFFSET => <time_difference> | STATEMENT => <id> } ]
  [ COPY GRANTS ]
  [ ... ]
```

The [ ... ] is not documented in https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/conventions.html .

Answer (score 3):

That's an ellipsis. It is standard English for "and so on", here meaning "more clauses / statements could go here". It's like *etcetera*.

Comment: Sure I got that as well, but my question was rather targeting which clauses exactly?
It could be any of the clauses of the general form, but then why is (in the last two forms) COPY GRANTS explicitly listed prior to the ellipsis, knowing that COPY GRANTS is also one of the optional clauses in the general form?

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, [ COPY GRANTS ] is called out specifically in each of the syntax "variations" because these keywords must be ordered as presented; whereas, the ordering of other keywords or properties for the CREATE TABLE command does not matter.